# Fastify - return statement or rep.send(), are they the same thing?

Tags: node.js, fastify

I've seen quite a few different examples of this. I've seen code that has return statements and code that only has rep.send() but I'm still not clear whether rep.send() is equivalent to return.

In the below example, will the second rep.send() get hit due to the first not having a return before it or will the code stop executing after the first rep.send() is triggered?

```
if (!transaction) {
    rep.code(204).send({ message: 'No previously used bank found' })
}

rep.code(200).send(transaction)
```

Comment: A function will end on a return or an exception; otherwise it keeps on going *(generally speaking)*. Whether or not it **matters** if it keeps on going depends on context. I don’t recall how Fastify works but generally if you try to send two responses it’s a development-time error and would be reported as such.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, fastify async framework.

```
if (!transaction) {
    return rep.code(204).send({ message: 'No previously used bank found' })
}

return rep.code(200).send(transaction) // don't send if equals !transaction
```

Comment: I'm sorry, are you saying return is required as I've seen many examples in the Fastify docs where it's not using a return statment.